# How do I login to this site?

Tags: support, login

This site drives me crazy! I'm a web developer. I understand technology, I understand OpenID, but I don't have a clue how to login to this site with the username I created whilst asking another question unless I ask yet another question?

Sure, this is a techie site but if I can't work out how to log in then what hope is OpenID to the rest of the non technical world?

Comment: I realise that might sound grumpy but it's a genuine question about the ease of use of OpenID. It seems like a great idea but the process in confusing.

What's strange is that I seem to have 3 disparate accounts on here now.

Comment: Did this question migrate twice? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51662/how-do-i-login-to-this-site

Comment: @Robert Yes, 6 close votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I merged all your accounts.

This can happen if you don't use the "register" link to convert your cookie-based account into an openid account.

Answer (score 0):

There's a "Log In" link at the very top of the page, in the gray box with the search bar. Is that what you were having trouble finding? Or is it that the login process presented there doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: Hi, I've found the "log in" link but I couldn't log in with the user account that was created when I asked a question a few days back.

I have an account here:
http://stackoverflow.com/users/334644/kevin-monk

and here:
http://stackoverflow.com/users/353292/kevin-monk

and here:
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147514/kevin-monk

The last being an account created when I asked a meta-stackoverflow question in stackoverflow.

I actually wanted to login with the first account so I could vote up an answer someone had put there.

Comment: To answer your question more directl, the log in process presented here doesn't make sense to me.

I can create a user account by asking  question but then I can never log back in to the account?

I'd really like to log in under stackoverflow.com/users/334644/kevin-monk so that all my question are consolidated in one place.